# JSONPath Query in array

Tags: json, jsonpath

Here is my JSON :

```
[
  {
    "Data": [
      {
        "Count": null,
        "TimeStamp": "2023-03-18T09:56:00Z",
        "Average": null,
        "Maximum": 0.4,
        "Minimum": null,
        "Total": null
      }
    ],
    "Name": {
      "LocalizedValue": "DTU used",
      "Value": "dtu_used"
    },
    "Unit": "Count"
  },
  {
    "Data": [
      {
        "Count": null,
        "TimeStamp": "2023-03-18T09:56:00Z",
        "Average": null,
        "Maximum": 20.0,
        "Minimum": null,
        "Total": null
      }
    ],
    "Name": {
      "LocalizedValue": "DTU Limit",
      "Value": "dtu_limit"
    },
    "Unit": "Count"
  }
]
```

I am trying to get the value of Data.*.Maximum in the same array where Name.Value = 'dtu_limit'.

I can get the values of Maximum with `$.*.Data.*.Maximum` but I don't know how to filter.

I tried things like this but that doesn't work : `$.*[?(@.Name.Value == 'dtu_used')].Data.*.Maximum`

Please help !

Comment: `$[?(@.Name.Value=="dtu_limit")].Data.*.Maximum` Works fine for me. So without the `.*` after `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...doesn't work : `$.*[?(@.Name.Value == 'dtu_used')].Data.*.Maximum`

You need to remove that first `.*`. So either:

```
$[?(@.Name.Value == 'dtu_used')].Data.*.Maximum
```

or

```
$[?(@.Name.Value == 'dtu_limit')].Data.*.Maximum
```

Depending on which value you want to filter by.